# FIeld Service Lightning - Book Appointment error

Tags: managed-package

I am configuring FSL app in my org, but while using book appointment global action, I get the below error.

line 1427, column 1: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Cannot add address to resource absence with record type 'Break': []

I am not sure why this happens .

Thanks

Comment: You will need to post the relevant code/validation rule if you are looking for help debugging it

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same failure. I have figured out that it is the following Managed Validation which cause the problem "NoAddressOnBreaks".

AND( $RecordType.Name ='Break' , 
NOT(ISBLANK(Street) && 
ISBLANK(City) && 
ISBLANK(Country) && 
ISBLANK(State) && 
ISBLANK(PostalCode)  ))

Since I try to book an appointment I cannot figure out why the Global Action also look into the "Resource Absense" object.